# Using Jquery in Controller Page-ASP.NET MVC-3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Could any one give an example, how to use Jquery in **Controller Page.** MVC3 -ASP.NET(How To put various tags like )

I want to show a simple alert before rendering a view in Controller.

Thank you.
Hari Gillala

Answer (score 0):

Normally scripts are part of the views. Controllers shouldn't be tied to javascript. So inside a view you use the `<script>` tag where you put javascript. So for example if you wanted to show an alert just before rendering a view you could put the following in the `<head>` section of this view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('simple alert');
</script>
```

As far as jQuery is concerned, it usually is used to manipulate the DOM so you would wrap all DOM manipulation functions in a `document.ready` (unless you include this script tag at the end, just before closing the `<body>`):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        // ... put your jQuery code here
    });
</script>
```

If you are talking about rendering partial views with AJAX that's another matter. You could have a link on some page that is pointing to a controller action:

```
@Html.ActionLink("click me", "someAction", null, new { id = "mylink" })
```

and a div container somewhere on the page:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

Now you could unobtrusively AJAXify this link and inject the resulting HTML into the div:

```
$(function() {
    $('#mylink').click(function() {
        $('#result').load(this.href, function() {
            alert('AJAX request finished => displaying results in the div');
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Please leave a comment when downvoting explaining why this answer is wrong.